# How I can get only row from same id_category and id_service with the max date of them

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, max

I have this table:

```
id_category | id_service | amount | date
```

This table have more than one rows with same id_category and id_service. How I can get only row from same id_category and id_service with the max date of them?

Example data:

```
1 | 1 | 0.1  | 2015-05-05
1 | 1 | 0.12 | 2015-05-06
1 | 2 | 0.2  | 2015-05-04
1 | 2 | 0.25 | 2015-05-05
1 | 2 | 0.30 | 2015-05-06
2 | 1 | 0.15 | 2015-05-05
```

I want to get this results:

```
1 | 1 | 0.12 | 2015-05-06
1 | 2 | 0.30 | 2015-05-06
2 | 1 | 0.15 | 2015-05-05
```

Thanks!

Comment: You included the solution in your question's tags: `GROUP BY`. Provide the query you have tried and we can work out evetual problems together.

Comment: Anyways, look at the first *related question* listed right here on the right: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad96b/3

```
SELECT t1.* 
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t1 t2
ON t1.id_category = t2.id_category
   AND t1.id_service = t2.id_service
   AND t1.`date` < t2.`date`
WHERE t2.date IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your query like this

```
select a.* from table a
where a.date = 
(select max(b.date) from table b where a.id=b.id group by b.id_service, b.id_category)
group by a.id_category, a.id_service;
```

Comment: Yout table column id | id_category | id_service | amount | date

Answer (score 0):

You can use derived table then use inner join

**MYSQL Version** [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a628d/18)

```
SELECT gd.*, t.amount
FROM (Select id_category, id_service, max(date) date
      FROM t
      group by id_category, id_service)  gd
INNER JOIN t ON gd.id_service = t.id_service 
                AND gd.id_category = t.id_category
                AND gd.date = t.date
ORDER BY gd.id_category, gd.id_service
```

**MSSQL Version**:- This will be get with CTE if SQL Server  [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a628d/17)

```
;WITH GroupedData AS
   (
       select id_category, id_service, max(date) date
       FROM t
       group by id_category, id_service       
   ) 
   SELECT gd.*, t.amount
   FROM GroupedData  gd
   INNER JOIN t ON gd.id_service = t.id_service 
                AND gd.id_category = t.id_category
                AND gd.date = t.date
   ORDER BY gd.id_category, gd.id_service
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select id_category, id_service, max(amount), min(date)
from table_name
group by id_category, id_service;
```

Comment: this will not work if max amount is bigger for other lower date

Comment: @Piyush I have tried that out and it works even if max amount is bigger for other lower date.

Comment: that works only current sample data, currently OP has sample data where max(amount) is always max where max(date), just change sample data for first sample row to this `1 | 1 | 0.15  | 2015-05-05`.    see this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/04498f/3....here it gives wrong amount field

Comment: I am afraid that I am still not agree with you. I tried changing the values and yet I am getting the expected results. Anyways Hernán got the answer I guess :)